# Ho do I prevent the Center of a 9-Patch File to be streached?

Tags: java, android, nine-patch

I want to use a 9-Patch image: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Using the draw9patch tool the center element which is the element in the second row and second column gets always streached. I want that the center element remains in the original dimension and that in will be centered on the screen.

**How can I do that with 9-Patch images?**

Comment: I dont really understand ur question try to add some picture what you want  spec..

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to draw a continuous line along the top/side. You can draw a dot/line near the left side, leave a gap in the center, and another black dot/line near the right side.

```
    *                   *
 +-------------------------+
 |                         |
*|                         |
 |                         |
 |                         |
 |                         |
*|                         |
 |                         |
 +-------------------------+
```